Why do they add 'la' before 'Señora Ramos'?
I was asked to translate the sentence
He has a business with Mrs. Ramos.

into Spanish.
I wrote
Él tiene un negocio con Señora Ramos.

but I failed, and the right answer was
Él tiene un negocio con la Señora Ramos.

I don't understand why there should be 'la' ahead of 'Señora Ramos'.

Even in English, but you can find instances of "the Lady XYZ", and Wikipedia says: 'A peeress's title is used with the definite article: Lord Morris's wife is "the Lady Morris".'

Complementing @RubioRic's answer, different cases can be considered:

Common name:

... con la doctora [... with the doctor]
... con la señora [... with the lady]


Family name with a title:

... con la doctora Ramos [... with Dr. Ramos]
... con la Señora Ramos [... with Mrs. Ramos]


Family name without a title:

... con Ramos [... with Ramos]


Given name with a title:

... con Doña María [with lady María]


Given name without a title:

... con María [with María]



The only difference with English (at least in this list) is when using both a title and a family name.

According to the DRAE

el / la

Artículo determinado, también llamado definido. Antecede siempre al sustantivo y su función principal es asociar el contenido semántico de
este con un referente concreto, consabido por los interlocutores: El
cartero ha pasado hoy un poco más tarde; o con un referente genérico:
El cerdo es un animal doméstico.


Let me try to translate it:

[El artículo] ... precedes always the sustantive and its main function
is to associate such sustantive's semantic content with a specific
reference known by both speakers: the postman came a bit later today.

Notice that "the" in the English version of the text before "postman". In Spanish we use "el/la" both before "postman" and before "Mrs.Ramos" because we are talking about a specific postman and a specific Mrs.Ramos.
Would you use "the" in your sentence in English if we replace Mrs.Ramos by postman? I think that the answer is yes.
Regarding the use of a definitive article before the first name. you can find the answer in the linked page


Uso con antropónimos. En la lengua culta, los nombres propios de persona se emplean normalmente sin artículo: Juan es un tipo
simpático; No he visto a María desde el mes pasado. La anteposición
del artículo, en estos casos, suele ser propia del habla popular: «Un
señor mayor chiquiaba mucho a la María» (Medina Cosas [Méx. 1990]). No
obstante, hay zonas del ámbito hispánico, por ejemplo en Chile, donde
esta anteposición se da también en el habla culta, habitualmente en
registros coloquiales y especialmente ante nombres de mujer


To summarize: you can use them colloquially but not in a formal context if you're not in Chile.

But would you use a definite article with only a first name? "Él tiene un negocio con la(?) Conchita".

@JannPoppinga I totally disagree with Vilarinof regarding the use of the article before the first name. I've edited my answer to include an excerpt from the DRAE answering your question. You can perfectly say "Él tiene un negocio con la Conchita". That form is pretty used but be aware that you shouldn't use it in a formal context.

It might be worth pointing out that you would normally translate "He has a business with Mrs. Ramos." as "Tiene un negocio" not "El tiene". You would only use "El tiene" to differentiate from someone else, but in the absence of such context "el tiene" seems odd.

@RubioRic Okay, but then your explanation that you need an article because you refer to a specific Mrs Ramos falls flat. (Because you're also talking about a specific Conchita.)

Vilarinof makes a great point about the mixed usage. Generally, señor/señora is traditionally used with surnames (e.g., la señora Pérez), while don/doña is used with first names (e.g., doña María).
And yes, generally señor/señora is preceded by an article when it isn't the subject of the sentence.
